# Published SSRS report default Parameter decimal places

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, default

SSRS 2008.

If I try to edit a Report Parameter from a published report's properties, it automatically formats the Parameter to two decimal places and round the value, even if I enter in a number with 3 or 4 decimal places.

The parameters are all set to Floats.  If I set the parameters in the report designer, it will keep the three or four decimal value and not round to two decimal places.

I am trying to setup linked reports, and parameters in linked reports have to be set in the published report's properties.

Any suggestion on overriding the default two decimal place rounding in the report properties?

Screenshot of report properties, automatically rounded to two decimal places:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to keep them as text and do math on them without any trouble-when you cast them as floats at the parameter level its going to truncate and round every time - if you make them strings you'll maintain the decimal points. You can always recast them later in the expression - say, CSNG() if you need to